# Consecutive string replacements in C

Tags: c, loops, optimization

Please see the following code, which performs consecutive character/string replacements by looping through all the utf8 characters to be replaced; would you propose another, more efficient, construct?

```
static char *utf8[66] =  { "◊",    "⎕",    "⍞",    "⌹",    "⊤",    "⊥",
                           "⌶",    "⌈",    "∪",    "⍕",    "⍎",    "│",
                           "⍟",    "∆",    "∇",    "→",    "←",    "⌊",
                           "┐",    "└",    "─",    "↑",    "↓",    "≡",
                           "⍸",    "⋸",    "∵",    "⌷",    "⍂",    "⌻",
                           "⊣",    "⊢",    "⋄",    "┘",    "┌",    "⍺",
                           "⊂",    "⊃",    "⍝",    "⍲",    "⍴",    "⍱",
                           "⌽",    "⊖",    "○",    "∨",    "⍳",    "⍬",
                           "∈",    "∩",    "⌿",    "⍀",    "≥",    "≤",
                           "≠",    "×",    "÷",    "⍙",    "∘",    "⍵",
                           "⍫",    "⍋",    "⍒",    "¯",    "¨",    NULL    };

static char *ebcdic[66] = { "\x8d", "\x90", "\x91", "\x92", "\x98", "\x9d",
                           "\x9f", "\xa9", "\xac", "\xae", "\xaf", "\xb3",
                           "\xb5", "\xb6", "\xb7", "\xb8", "\xbd", "\xbe",
                           "\xbf", "\xc0", "\xc4", "\xc6", "\xc7", "\xcf",
                           "\xd0", "\xd1", "\xd2", "\xd3", "\xd4", "\xd5",
                           "\xd6", "\xd7", "\xd8", "\xd9", "\xda", "\xe0",
                           "\xe2", "\xe3", "\xe4", "\xe5", "\xe6", "\xe7",
                           "\xe8", "\xe9", "\xea", "\xeb", "\xec", "\xed",
                           "\xee", "\xef", "\xf0", "\xf1", "\xf2", "\xf3",
                           "\xf4", "\xf5", "\xf6", "\xf7", "\xf8", "\xf9",
                           "\xfa", "\xfb", "\xfc", "\xfd", "\xfe", NULL    };

char* convert(char *line) {
  char *buffer1;
  char *buffer2;
  char *tmp;
  int i=0;

  buffer1 = malloc(strlen(line));
  strcpy(buffer1, line);
  while(ebcdic[i]) {
    buffer2 = replace(buffer1, utf8[i], ebcdic[i]);
    free(buffer1);
    buffer1 = malloc(strlen(buffer2));
    strcpy(buffer1, buffer2);
  }
  tmp = malloc(strlen(buffer1 + 1));
  sprintf(tmp, "%s\n", buffer1);

  free(buffer1);
  free(buffer2);
  return tmp;
}

char* replace(const char* s, const char* oldW, const char* newW) {
  char* result;
  int i, cnt = 0;
  int newWlen = strlen(newW);
  int oldWlen = strlen(oldW);

  for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    if (strstr(&s[i], oldW) == &s[i]) {
      cnt++;
      i += oldWlen - 1;
    }
  }
  result = (char*)malloc(i + cnt * (newWlen - oldWlen) + 1);
  i = 0;
  while (*s) {
    if (strstr(s, oldW) == s) {
      strcpy(&result[i], newW);
      i += newWlen;
      s += oldWlen;
    } else {
      result[i++] = *s++;
    }
  }
  result[i] = '\0';
  return result;
}
```

- update-001: added code for replace().
- update-002: changed for/loop to while.

Thank you for looking, I care about readability and memory usage more than performance in this particular case.

Comment: (a) Increase the length of the allocated space by one to allow for the null terminator. (b) Show the definition of `replace`. (c) Do not free a buffer and allocate new space, just reuse the same buffer. (d) Do not allocate a buffer to copy `line` at all; only allocate space for a new line. The input can be read directly from the buffer the user passes without being copied. (e) `sprintf(tmp, "%s\n", buffer1);` is absurd. Just put the desired data in `buffer1` (adding one more space in allocation for the newline character, if desired) and return that. (f) Buffers are left unfreed and ureturned.

Comment: Added the code for replace()

Comment: I would propose to write correct code first, then worry about efficiency. `while(ebcdic[i])` is obviously incorrect, it never terminates. `malloc(strlen(line))` is obviously incorrect. Having more `malloc`s than `free`s per iteration is obviously incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to write that code as a learning experience, otherwise scrape it a use an existing tool/library.

When you want to convert characters/codepoints, the basic algorithm goes like this:

Get next codepoint from input string, convert that codepoint (or keep as is), store the converted codepoint at end of output string. Repeat.

Since your input string uses one `char` per codepoint, getting the next codepoint is just as simple as looping through the 'char's in the input string. It also means that the codepoint conversion can be used by a simple lookup table of size 256 (assuming 8bit `char`s). The utf8 codepoints are not necessarily of length 1, so we have to account for that.

```
/* This syntax just means that the array is intialized with 
   ebdic2utf8_lut[0x8d] = "◊", ebdic2utf8_lut[0x90] = "⎕", etc.
   Array elements that are not explicit assigned in the initialization
   list will be initialized to `0` (or NULL) 
   We may treat array elements with value `0` as "keep as is" */

static const char *const ebdic2utf8_lut[256] = {
  [0x8d] = "◊",
  [0x90] = "⎕",
  [0x91] = "⍞",
  [0x92] = "⌹",
  /* Rest of initializations left out for brevity */
};

char * convert(const char *src)
{
   /* Allocate space for empty string*/
   char *dst = calloc(1, 1);
   if (!dst)
      {
         perror("String allocation failed");
         exit(1);
      }

   size_t dst_length = 0;

   while(*src)
     {
        /* We want to lose the sign of `char` for the lut */
        unsigned char ch = *src;

        /* Convert next character */
        const char *utf8 = ebdic2utf8_lut[ch];

        /* If there is no conversion we keep it as is
           But the rest of the function works with strings, so we
           put the input character in a string with length 1 */
        char keep_as_is[2];
        if (!utf8)
          {
            keep_as_is[0] = ch;
            keep_as_is[1] = '\0'; /* Zero termination */
            utf8 = keep_as_is;
          }

        size_t utf8_length = strlen(utf8);

        size_t new_dst_length = dst_length + utf8_length;

        /* Resize destination string to allow for appending 
           (including zero-termination) */
        char *new_dst = realloc(dst, new_dst_length + 1);
        if (!new_dst)
          {
            perror("String resize failed");
            exit(1);
          }
        dst = new_dst;

        /* Append converted character to destination string*/ 
        strcpy(dst + dst_length, utf8);


        dst_length = new_dst_length;
        src++;
     }

   return dst;
} 

int main(void)
{
  char *str = convert("Hello\x90\x91\x92World");

  /* This should print "Hello⎕⍞⌹World", unless you are under Windows.
     Windows and utf-8 doesn't mix very well */
  printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

This code has not been checked for errors, use at own risk, etc..

Comment: few questions:
Looks like dst_length is kept to zero? (should it be size_t?)
and char* dst=malloc(1)?

Comment: Yes, `dst_length` should be `size_t` (fixed now). Its length is not kept zero, it is updated in the loop. Other fix: `src` is incremented in the loop rather than `dst`. (`dst` is still updated by `realloc`)

Comment: If you use `dst=malloc(1)` rather than `dst=calloc(1)`, then the destination string will not be zero-terminated when empty. Later `strcpy` will add zero termination, but this depends on the source-string not being empty, and the code entering the loop.  If you prefer to use `malloc`, you can do that, but then you should add `dst[0] = '\0'` right after `malloc` to catch the case when `src` is empty.

Comment: Doesn't calloc() takes 2 arguments?

Comment: please find the following gist https://gist.github.com/jibanes/712a8c5ac5640b1730a1dc7da4217678 . When I call convert("123⍳123") it prints d8 d8 d8 d8 d8 d8 d8 d8 d8 here.

Comment: Yes,  `calloc` takes 2 arguments, and if you had used a debugger you would probably have seen that `ch` gets a weird value for some `*src` (it should have been declared `unsigned char`, not `unsigned int`). The answer is only meant as a guide on how to solve a problem, not as a complete turn-key solution. Some debugging/adaption is always necessary. That said, I am still interested in any bugs you find, so I can fix the code.

Comment: And btw, your `printf` is wrong, use `printf("%hhx ", (unsigned char)dst[i]);`. And see my comment about the use of `malloc`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225486/discussion-between-jerome-ibanes-and-hal9000).

Answer (score 0):

To convert from utf8 to ebdic, it is still possible to use a lookuptable. But having a LUT going from utf8->ebdic is impractical because of its size. But we can use an ebdic->utf8 LUT and loop through it to find a match.

The basic algorithm for the string conversion, is basically still the same, get
the next utf8 codepoint/character in input string, convert that to ebdic, push the converted char to output string (or push one char if no conversion was found), remove the prefix from input string, repeat.

When doing utf8->ebdic conversion, we have to be aware that an utf8 codepoint may be multiple bytes. So we have to compare multiple bytes in the prefix of the input string, and we must also increment the input string with multiple bytes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


static const char *const ebdic2utf8_lut[256] = {
  [0x8d] = "◊", [0x90] = "⎕", [0x91] = "⍞", [0x92] = "⌹",
  [0x98] = "⊤", [0x9d] = "⊥", [0x9f] = "⌶", [0xa9] = "⌈",
  [0xac] = "∪", [0xae] = "⍕", [0xaf] = "⍎", [0xb3] = "│",
  [0xb5] = "⍟", [0xb6] = "∆", [0xb7] = "∇", [0xb8] = "→",
  [0xbd] = "←", [0xbe] = "⌊", [0xbf] = "┐", [0xc0] = "└",
  [0xc4] = "─", [0xc6] = "↑", [0xc7] = "↓", [0xcf] = "≡",
  [0xd0] = "⍸", [0xd1] = "⋸", [0xd2] = "∵", [0xd3] = "⌷",
  [0xd4] = "⍂", [0xd5] = "⌻", [0xd6] = "⊣", [0xd7] = "⊢",
  [0xd8] = "⋄", [0xd9] = "┘", [0xda] = "┌", [0xe0] = "⍺",
  [0xe2] = "⊂", [0xe3] = "⊃", [0xe4] = "⍝", [0xe5] = "⍲",
  [0xe6] = "⍴", [0xe7] = "⍱", [0xe8] = "⌽", [0xe9] = "⊖",
  [0xea] = "○", [0xeb] = "∨", [0xec] = "⍳", [0xed] = "⍬",
  [0xee] = "∈", [0xef] = "∩", [0xf0] = "⌿", [0xf1] = "⍀",
  [0xf2] = "≥", [0xf3] = "≤", [0xf4] = "≠", [0xf5] = "×",
  [0xf6] = "÷", [0xf7] = "⍙", [0xf8] = "∘", [0xf9] = "⍵",
  [0xfa] = "⍫", [0xfb] = "⍋", [0xfc] = "⍒", [0xfd] = "¯",
  [0xfe] = "¨" };


/* Match an utf8 string with prefix in `str` and return the corresponding
   ebdic character */

char utf8lookup(const char *str, size_t *increment)
{
  for (size_t n = 0; n < 256; n++)
    {
      const char *utf8 = ebdic2utf8_lut[n];
      if (utf8)
    {
      size_t len = strlen(utf8);
      if (strncmp(str, utf8, len) == 0)
        {
          *increment = len;
          return (char)n;
        }
    }
    }
  return 0;
}



char * convert_u2e(const char *src)
{
   /* Allocate space for empty string*/
   char *dst = calloc(1, 1);
   if (!dst)
      {
         perror("String allocation failed");
         exit(1);
      }

   size_t dst_length = 0;

   while(*src)
     {

       /* Convert next character */
       size_t src_increment;
       char ch = utf8lookup(src, &src_increment);

       /* If there is no conversion we the first character int `src` as is */
        if (!ch)
          {
        ch = *src;
        src_increment = 1;
          }

        size_t new_dst_length = dst_length + 1;

        /* Resize destination string to allow for appending 
           (including zero-termination) */
        char *new_dst = realloc(dst, new_dst_length + 1);
        if (!new_dst)
          {
            perror("String resize failed");
            exit(1);
          }
        dst = new_dst;

        /* Append converted character to destination string*/ 
        dst[dst_length] = ch;

        dst_length = new_dst_length;
        src += src_increment;
     }

   /* Zero terminate */
   dst[dst_length] = '\0';
   
   return dst;
} 

int main(void)
{
  char *str = convert_u2e("Hello⎕⍞⌹World");

  for (const char *s = str; *s; s++)
    printf("%hhx ", (unsigned char)*s);
  printf("\n");

  free(str);
}
```